# Are there integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^4+y^2=4321^{4321}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Are there integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^4+y^2=4321^{4321}$? Prove your answer.

I do not know how to approach this question. Would using modular arithmetic work?

Comment: First of all, note that $$4321=6^4+55^2$$ Then, consider that $4321^{4320}$ is a fourth power. Do you have an idea how to represent your number in the desired form ?

Comment: How the heck did you figure out $6^4 + 55^2 = 4321$?

Comment: With a computer program!

Comment: I found the question. In fact it was deleted (and with it my answer), but not by the author of the question. I guess because it was the answer to a math-contest-question. I do not have another explanation.

Comment: @Peter Which math contest?

Comment: The question was marked as a contest. No idea what kind of contest. But it must be important, if answers apparantly should not be posted here.

Comment: @Peter I can see how it works but I can't explain it... should I do a paragraph proof?

Comment: I can't feel comfortable taking peter's observation for granted but once it is made $4321^{4321} = 4321^{4320}*4321 = 4321^{4320}(6^4 + 55^2)$ and so  ... but I think the heart of the problem is solving $x^4 + y^2 = 4321$.  I don't feel we can just claim an answer.

Comment: @fleablood How would knowing $4321^{4321}=4321^{4320}(6^4+55^2)$ help?

Comment: @suomynonA Once we have this representation, the rest is easy because $4320$ is a multiple of $4$, hence $4321^{4320}$ is a fourth power.

Comment: If $x^4 + y^2 = c$ then $(c^{(c-1)/4}x)^4 + (c^{(c-1)/2}y)^2 = c*c^{c-1}=c^c$.

Comment: @fleablood To check whether $4321-k^4$ is a square for $k=0,1,2,\cdots,8$ will not take too long, even if done by hand. We can stop at $k=8$ because of $4321-9^4<0$. Here we are lucky and actually find a representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in comments, we can solve the given problem if we can solve $r^4 + s^2 = 4321.$ Since $4320 = 4 \cdot 1080,$ we then take $( 4321^{1080} r)^4 + (4321^{2160} s)^2 = 4321^{4321}$

$$ 4321 = 29 \cdot 149  $$
$$  29 = 25 + 4 = 5^2 + 2^2  $$
$$ 149 = 100 + 49 = 10^2 + 7^2  $$
$$  (5,2)(10,7) $$

[Brahmagupta's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta's_identity)  both ways, with $n=1.$

$$ (64,15)  (55, 36) $$
Two ways,
$$ 4321 = 8^4 + 15^2 = 55^2 + 6^4 $$

Comment: I'm finding $x^2+y^2=4321^{4321}$, not $x^2+y^2=4321$ though

Comment: If $4321 = 55^2 + 6^4$ then $4321*4321^{4320} = (55^2 + 6^4)4321^{4320} = (55*4321^{2160})^2 + (5*4321^{1080})^4$.

Comment: @fleablood yes, I added that to the answer, perhaps while you were typing

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Will Jagy's approach, once you've decided to see if there are solutions to $4321=r^4+s^2$, the inequality $r^4\le4321$ implies $r\le\sqrt[4]{4321}\approx8.1$, so there are only nine cases to check:

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{4321-0^4}&=65.73\ldots\\
\sqrt{4321-1^4}&=65.72\ldots\\
&\vdots\\
\sqrt{4321-8^4}&=15
\end{align}$$

You can probably rule out some of the square roots for congruence reasons, but it might be quicker at this point just to compute them.  In any event, only two of them are integers, namely when $r=8$, which gives $s=15$ as shown, and when $r=6$, which gives $s=55$.

Comment: right. Probably quicker than factoring 4321 as well. I usually start at the easy end, take $8^4$ off and see what's left.

Comment: @WillJagy, agreed.  I started with $0^4$ because I either know or can easily compute the first few fourth powers in my head.  I suppose I "know" $4096$ too, but I have to think to get $1296$, and if I try to get $2401$ in my head I wind up with a headache....